# Page missing when printing a report with Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm using Report-designer 3.6.1, and I encountered a recurring problem with one of my reports.

When I print the report, sometimes the result is missing pages. The report prints seven pages out of nine, the last page displaying a page count of 7/9. Also on the last page, the footer is missing as if it were not configured.

This problem happens randomly (or in a particular pattern that I can't grasp). All other reports are fine. They all print the footer, and all the pages.

If you need more info leave comments, I will try to respond to the best of my knowledge, because I am new with this tool.

Here is how we setup the report

**Master report**:

- *Page header*

  1. Some fields that are printed on each page;
- *Details*

  1. Sub-report #1: List all attributes of each product;
- *Report Footer*

  1. Empty
- *Page Footer*

  1. Some text fields;
  2. Page count (totalPageCount function);

**Sub-report #1**:

- *Group Header*: Empty;
- *Detail*

  1. Collumn headers;
  2. Sub-report #2: List some attribute values for each product;
- *Group Footer*
- *Report Footer*

  1. Text field with a message.

**Sub-report #2**:

- *Detail*

  1. Attribute's name;
- *Report Footer*: Attribute's value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

**Source**: I found out that my sub-report #2 was probably overlapping the header's columns from the Sub-report #1.

**Solution**: I moved the Sub-report #2 down by approximately 10px, so that it doesn't overlap anymore.

After that, the report printed out with all the necessary pages.